# React table is loading all the data in one go instead of server side pagination

Tags: reactjs, datatable, axios, server-side-rendering, react-table

I am using react-table version 6.9.2 to connect to an API and display the data. I am following the basis of this example:

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#server-side-data

The issue I am facing currently is that the API is loading all the data on App load which is not ideal. I am trying to enable server side pagination so that it loads 10 rows per page but it doesn't seem to be working as all 100 rows get loaded on App start.

Current code:

```
<ReactTable
  onFetchData={(state, instance) => {
    // show the loading overlay
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    // fetch your data
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
        page: state.page,
        pageSize: state.pageSize,
        sorted: state.sorted,
        filtered: state.filterd
      })
      .then(res => {
        // Update react-table
        this.setState({
          posts: res.data,
          data: res.data,
          page: state.page,
          pages: res.data.pages,
          loading: false
        });
      });
  }}
  columns={columns}
  data={this.state.data}
  pages={this.state.pages}
  loading={this.state.loading}
  filterable
  defaultPageSize={10}
  noDataText={"Loading..."}
  manual // informs React Table that you'll be handling sorting and pagination server-side
/>
```

The option of `defaultPageSize={10}` doesn't get applied. When I remove the manual property, it works but when you click through each page it requests all 100 rows every time. The example which displays the functionality I am looking for is in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-server-side-data

My current sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/v0vr0jqmwy

I've been stuck on this for ages and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

I found two problem.

1. In the network tab of the developer tool you can see, that the get parameters are not filled up. You can fix it by altering the axios call, adding the params property.

   ```
     axios
       .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",{ params: {
         page: state.page,
         pageSize: state.pageSize,
         sorted: state.sorted,
         filtered: state.filterd
       }})
   ```
2. Even if you provide the get parameters, your api at jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts appareantly do not takes into account these parameters.

Comment: I see. Should I use an alternative API or is there something else I need to change in my code? I plan on connecting this to a large database hence why I want to load only a certain number of rows per page as opposed to all of them currently.

The "manual" option is supposed to inform react table that sorting and pagination will be server-side but that is not working..not sure if I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @jsnoobie I think if you switch api, it will be much better.